# Working version of html2latex tool?

Tags: html2latex

I've been trying to find a working version of the html2latex perl script, and so far all I've found are semi-correct, out dated versions.

Is someone maintaining this tool somewhere, with up-to-date bug fixes etc...? Any up-to-date ports to other languages would work for me, too.